# Nodejs how to visit global val in callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

I defined a val in global, and I hope to access this var in a function's callback, the code is like below:

```
exports.ready_to_exit = false;

function send2kafkaImpl(payloads, cb) {
  kproducer.send(payloads, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      if (ready_to_exit) {
          console.log('ready to exit');
          process.exit();
      } else {
        return cb();
      }
    }

    console.log(new Date() + ' Kafka error: ', err.message || err);
    send2kafkaImpl(payloads, cb);
  });
}
```

when I run this code, got error:

> ```
>  if (ready_to_exit) {
>       ^ ReferenceError: ready_to_quit is not defined
> ```

Comment: Use `exports.ready_to_exit`. There is no global variable `ready_to_exit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make a variable global you should set it as a property of `global` object. Change:

```
exports.ready_to_exit = false;
```

To:

```
global.ready_to_exit = false;
```